# Cloudsearch starting date and now

Tags: php, reddit, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to retrieve data from Reddit using cloudsearch, I always need all posts starting a programmatically set date, let's say yesterday. I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for MySQL equivalent `WHERE timestamp > 1420070400`.

Only thing I've found out up to now is how to retrieve posts from a given range, for example `timestamp:1410739200..1411171200`. I know that I can take the current date and convert it to epoch but that is prone to error because it depends on my server date which is why I want to avoid.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave one of the sides unbounded:

- `timestamp:1460678641..` searches all posts starting at April 15th
- `timestamp:..1262304000` searches all posts from before 2010

The mistake I made when testing is that I didn't append `syntax=cloudsearch` parameter to Reddit and while it detects automatically cloudsearch if you feed it a range, it won't if you give it just one date.

Thanks to /u/Pokechu22 on Reddit for clarifications https://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/4g3hbn/cloudsearch_timestamp/